# Find the pdf and expectation of the maximum of a sequence of iid uniform random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, uniform-distribution

Given a sequence of uniform random variables $(0, x)$, how do you find the PDF and expectation of the maximum?

I know the PDF of any one variable is $\frac{1}{x}$ and the CDF is $x$, and since they're independent, you can get a JCDF by multiplying them together.

Working from the JCDF:

$P(X_n \leqslant x)=P(X_1 \leqslant x)*...*P(X_n \leqslant x)=(F(x))^n$

And if you differentiate this wrt $x$,  this you get $n(F(x))^{n-1}f(x)$... is this process correct?

Then E(X) is usually the integral of $xf(x)$, but I'm not sure how to apply that here.

Help appreciated!

Comment: There are a few typos in your write-up. If the interval is indeed $(0,x)$ as you say, then you should pick $Y =  max \left\{X_i\right\}_{i=1}^n$ to be $\leq$ some value $y$, to avoid confusion.

Comment: The notation is confusing. Do you mean to say that the r.v.'s are independent but have different support? If so, what are the upper bounds for $(0,x)$? Maybe integers?

Comment: @mlc They say "iid", so I think $x$ is either a constant (and they typo'd everything else in the write-up), or that it's something else entirely in the support.

Comment: Oops yeah the interval is 0 and a constant -- I just typed x, obviously to very confusing results, sorry

Comment: @user61871 Quite a bit of that write-up needs to be changed. The CDF is not $x$ for instance.

Comment: Anyway, the process itself looks fine. Have you tried substituting the values of $F(x)$ and $f(x)$ and then just solving that integral in the limits $(0,constant)$?

Comment: Oh wait should the CDF be x/constant? l was looking at the CDF formula on wikipedia, will try the int now :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x>0$ and $X_n\stackrel{\mathrm{i.i.d.}}\sim U(0,x)$. For each $0<t<x$ we have
$$
\left \{\max_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n} U_i \leqslant t\right\} = \bigcap_{i=1}^n \{U_i\leqslant t\},
$$
and by independence,
$$
\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n \{U_i\leqslant t\}\right) = \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb P(U_i\leqslant t).
$$
Let $V:=\max_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n} U_i$. Since the $U_i$ have the same distribution function $F_U(t) = \frac tx\mathsf 1_{(0,x)}(t)$, it follows that 
$$
F_V(t)= \mathbb P\left(V \leqslant t\right) = \left(\frac tx\right)^n\mathsf 1_{(0,x)}(t).
$$
The density of $V$ is obtained by differentiating:
$$
f_V(t) = \frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf dt} F_V(t) = \frac nx\left(\frac tx\right)^{n-1}\mathsf 1_{(0,x)}(t).
$$
The expectation of $V$ is computed as follows:
$$
\mathbb E[V] = \int_\mathbb R tf_V(t)\ \mathsf dt = \int_0^x n\left(\frac tx\right)^n\ \mathsf dt = \left(\frac n{n+1}\right)x.
$$